# Intersection in a Loop - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I need to find intersection (destination numbers) between thousands of calling numbers, i.e, I have the below data frame:

```
Calling Number | Called Number | Seconds
023456738      | 9123457583    | 55
064785993      | 8804783937    | 125
087594937      | 9123457583    | 34
087594937      | 9278446356    | 33
023456738      | 6547485959    | 45
087594937      | 3547483946    | 23
```

As per example, 023456738  has called 2 numbers and 087594937  has called 3 numbers, this number 9123457583 is the common between the 2 numbers: 023456738 and 087594937.

My desired output is:

```
Calling Number1 | Calling Number2| Intersect Count | Intersect Value
023456738       | 087594937      | 1               | 9123457583
```

What I did is I took the unique in Calling Number (using `.unique()`) and then put in loop (i,j combination), then check if there is a common number between the i and j. Please see my code, merged2 is the dataframe as per above. SRC is calling number and DST is the Called number.

```
#library
import pandas as pd
import itertools

merged2.sort_values('DST', inplace=True)

array_src = merged2.SRC.unique()

def intersect(lst1, lst2):
    # Use of hybrid method
    temp = set(lst2)
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in temp]
    return lst3

df = pd.DataFrame(columns['SRC1','SRC2','Intersect_count','Intersect_value'])


for i, j in itertools.product(array_src, array_src):
    if i == j:
        continue
    dfA = merged2[(merged2['SRC'] == i)].copy()
    array_Adst = dfA.DST.unique()
    dfB = merged2[(merged2['SRC'] == j)].copy()
    array_Bdst = dfB.DST.unique()
    print i,j

    if len(intersect(array_Adst,array_Bdst))>0:
        print i,j
        Intersect_count = len(intersect(array_Adst,array_Bdst))
        Intersect_value = intersect(array_Adst,array_Bdst)
        print Intersect
        #       add them to a dataframe
        lister = [[i, j, Intersect_count,Intersect_value]]
        dfi = pd.DataFrame(lister, columns=['SRC1', 'SRC2','Intersect_count','Intersect_value'])
        df = df.append(dfi)
    else:
        continue

print df.head()
```

The issue I'm getting is that It's taking too long to run as if I got 100,000 Calling numbers, its going to do it for combination of 100,000C2. As per example,  it's going to take first number 023456738 and check with 064785993, 087594937, 023456738 and then number 064785993 with 087594937..

Can you please assist me in optimizing the codes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer: make use of Matrices.

First do a cross tabulation between the SRC and DST and then convert it to a binary matrix. We then do its transpose and then multiply both.

The diagonal represents the unique numbers of DST number each SRC called and the non-diagonal represents the intersection of DST between 2 SRC